# MySQL CASE - How to handle multiple results for a single CASE statement

Tags: mysql

I hope I am using the correct terminology in my title, but I have this (simplified) SQL statement:

```
SELECT name,  
MAX(CASE WHEN org_assigned_role= "CFO" THEN username END) "CFO",
MAX(CASE WHEN org_assigned_role= "CIO" THEN username END) "CIO"
FROM `wp_hubspot` , `wp_hubspot_companies` where company_id=comp_id 
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY name
```

The problem is that I have 2 CFOs in my table and I want both of their names in the single field/column "CFO".  Is that possible?

Thank you

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want:

```
select name,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN org_assigned_role="CFO" THEN username END ORDER BY username SEPARATOR ", ") "CFO",
    MAX(CASE WHEN org_assigned_role= "CIO" THEN username END) "CIO"
    FROM `wp_hubspot` , `wp_hubspot_companies` where company_id=comp_id 
    GROUP BY name
```

If what you mean is you want the two on separate rows, there are multiple results like that you could mean and you will need to provide sample data and expected output.

Note that the result of GROUP_CONCAT is truncated at `@@group_concat_max_len` characters (defaults to 1024 in mysql and in older versions of mariadb).

Comment: Awesome! Yes, exactly.  Thank you so much. I don't think I ever would have figured that out on my own.